# How i can use Dynamic topic for Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api

give below the config of the Kafka to locthe al server
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory consumerFactory() {
        Map config = new HashMap<>();

```
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}


@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new 
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}



here I need to change the topic as a dynamic content
@KafkaListener(topics = "mytopic")
private void consume2(String Data) {
    String userID = null;
    String topic = null;
    String message = null;
    System.out.println(Data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like

@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topics}")

And set it as environment variable or application property?

Environment variable KAFKA_TOPICS=mytopic
application.properties kafka.topics=mytopic